# spring how to trigger creation of JpaTransactionManager bean for ChainedTransactionManager

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

We have an existing datasource which is from hibernate for our Spring Boot application.

We would now like to use Neo4j as well which requires its own transaction manager. This will result in two transaction managers.

Now from what we gather we need to use `ChainedTransactionManager` where we pass in `JpaTransactionManager` and `Neo4jTransactionManager` as the parameters.

The only problem is that when we create the ChainedTransaction manager, e.g. as follows

```
    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager chainedTransactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory,
                                                                Neo4jProperties properties,
                                                                ObjectProvider<TransactionManagerCustomizers> transactionManagerCustomizers) {
        JpaTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager = jpaTransactionManager(transactionManagerCustomizers.getIfAvailable());
        Neo4jTransactionManager neo4jTransactionManager = neo4jtransactionManager(sessionFactory, properties, transactionManagerCustomizers);
        return new ChainedTransactionManager(neo4jTransactionManager);
    }
```

Then the problem is that it seems like we need to copy and or write almost all of the code in `JpaBaseConfiguration` provided by Spring BECAUSE in the spring class it says.

```
    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        if (this.transactionManagerCustomizers != null) {
            this.transactionManagerCustomizers.customize(transactionManager);
        }
        return transactionManager;
    }
```

Where the method does not fire (I believe due to `@ConditionalOnMissingBean`). So how would we make this method run and create the JpaTransactionManager WHICH we can autowire before we create our manager.

At least if we cannot create the JpaTransactionManager we would like to have the other classes `EntityManagerFactoryBuilder` which are also annotated by `@ConditionalOnMissingBean` be created.

How could we achieve the above?

Comment: Do you extend the `JpaBaseConfiguration`? If so, you could simply call the methods for yourself.

Comment: `JpaBaseConfiguration` is abstract, and `HibernateJpaConfiguration` is not public either.